# Python- using a range in an if statement

Tags: python

```
if turn==1:
    random1 = random.randrange(1,24)
    if random1 == range(13,SaI,1):
        print("A")
    if random1 == range(1,SaS,1):
        print("B")

randomize1()
```

This code runs, but doesn't print. Is what I'm trying to do (make an if statement check a range, rather than a single number) possible? If so, what am I doing wrong? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `in` operator, for example:

```
if random1 in range(13,SaI,1):
```

Comment: Or `13 <= random1 < SaI`. If you do use `range`, in Python 2, you should use `xrange` instead, as `range` will actually create a list.

Comment: That works kindall, thank you very much! (Using the <= version, that is)